# unable to call javascript function using button's onclick event

Tags: php, html

My `display.php` file has the code for fetching data from database and display it in html table. I want to display this table on my index page only in the `<div> displayTable` section and for that I've called the `showTbale()` using onclick of my button `abc`. But the problem is that the function `showTable()` doesn't get called even though I've successfully called the `logoutEmp()` using the onclick of the `logoutButton`. I don't understand what's the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I tried using form action to call `display.php` but it displays the table in another white page which I don't want. Also I don't want to include `display.php` code in my index page.

say this is my index file :

```
<head>
<meta http-eqiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page_style.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

function logoutEmp()
{
  window.location="saveLogout.php";
}   

function showTable()
{
  var month= $('#mnth: selected').val();
  alert (month);

  $("#displayTable").load("display.php",{ mnth: month});
}   

</script>

<h1>Employee Account</h1>

<div id="logoutEmp">
<button type="button" id="logoutButton" onclick="logoutEmp()">Logout</button>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="shw">
<select name="mnth">
<option value="Jan">January</option>
<option value="Feb">February</option>
<option value="Mar">March</option>
<option value="Apr">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="Jun">June</option>
<option value="Jul">July</option>
<option value="Aug">August</option>
<option value="Sep">September</option>
<option value="Oct">October</option>
<option value="Nov">November</option>
<option value="Dec">December</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="abc" onclick="showTable()">Display</button> 


<div id="displayTable">
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the crazy backslash in your function? and try document.location.href="saveLogout.php" instead of window.location

Comment: You are calling "showTbale()" but your function name is showtable(). Is it a typo ?

Comment: if you already using jquery then you should assign the onclick with $('#logoutButton').click(function(){}) inside your $(document).ready()

Comment: @steven emm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location . Though, I agree on the backslash.

Comment: @Alxandr ok, i agree. But it should be window.location.href, not window.location

Comment: the backslash and the showTable not a problem...I've put them by mistake while editing the code

Comment: check out my answer and demo, that should work for you

Comment: @steven not according to documentation. Sure, that's an **option**, but if you look at the link in my last comment, the first example (syntax) uses `window.location = newLocation;`.

Comment: if you use a button just to perform a `window.location` redirect, use a plain anchor w/ `href` instead.

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this:

```
function logoutEmp(){
 window.location.href="saveLogout.php";
 }
```

You had an extra slash, and a syntax error.

Also, you should change `showTable` that was wrong as well :

```
function showTable()
{
  var month= $('#mnth').val();
  alert (month);

 $("#displayTable").load("display.php",{ mnth: month});
 }
```

And add your id to your select:

```
<select name="mnth" id="mnth">
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/fHgKt/) my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

```
function logoutEmp()
{
 window.location="saveLogout.php";
 \}
```

that backslash should not be there:

```
function logoutEmp()
{
 window.location="saveLogout.php";
}
```

you can not call `showTable()` because in JavaScript if there is any error script after that error would not work.

Comment: why is everyone giving solution to logoutEmp()...thats working fine...I'm asking why i'm unable to call showTable() using onclick